# Modal "bounce" causing issues with vertical swipes within modal signature pad

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

As in the image below, I have a modal View Controller that has a nested signature view inside. This view is presented when a "show signature" button is tapped. I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to register vertical swipes within the signature view as it attempts to dismiss the modal. I've attempted to set `vc.isModalInPresentation = true` within the presentation code, as well as  `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and those both don't produce the results I need with the `isModalInPresentation` still causing a "bounce" effect on pulls up or down which interrupts drawing the signature, and `isUserInteractionEnabled` just cancelling all interaction.

What it needs to accomplish is:

- Signature needs to be able to be written within the view by touch (SignatureView needs to receive the touch, already have this capturing the signature, just vertical swipes cause the dismissal)
- The SignatureViewController needs to ignore the dismissal swipe gesture unless it's outside of the SignatureView(i.e. in the "clear" section of the view, above or below the main signature "pad").

Gestures aren't my forte, so any help is appreciated!

[image: image of modal view controller over the main view]

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Having a similar issue.